# How to fix the error "Statemachine is not in state ready to do DELETE"

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created a spring cloud data flow Stream with Gemfire as Source, Log as Sink and rabbitMQ for the messages to process. I was able to successfully deploy the stream on one of our boxes. However, when I deploy the same stream (with same configurations), I am getting the below error:

```
Command failed
org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Statemachine is not in state ready to do DELETE
```

If I try to delete the stream for re-deploy I get another error and unable to destroy the stream. Please throw some light if someone had a similar issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: App xxxx is already deployed with state failed
```

Answer (score 0):

From this specific error message:

```
ERROR 2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: App xxxx is already deployed with state failed
```

It looks like you are trying to deploy a stream that is in a failed state. You need to undeploy the stream first and try to re-deploy.

This can also happen when you have Skipper and Spring Cloud Data Flow servers' databases out of sync. For instance, you might be trying to create the stream which was created and deployed by a different instance of SCDF server.

Before you start creating/deploying the stream, you can check the stream history if there exists a stream with the same name already on Skipper.

Comment: Also running into this issue now:

`error waiting to get Release from state machine`

Undeployed and redeployed stream without success.